# What time complexity is this function?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I have been given a small and simple function to refactor into a function that is O(n) complexity. However, i believe the function given already is, unless I am missing something?

Basically the idea of the function is simply to iterate over a list and remove the target item.

```
for i in self.items:
        if i == item:
            self.items.pop(i)
```

I know the for loop gives this a O(n) complexity but does the additional if statement add to the complexity? I didn't think it did in the worst-case for this simple piece of code.

If it does, is there a way this can be re-written to be O(n)?

I cannot think of another way to iterate over a list and remove an item without using a For loop and then using an if statement to do the comparison?

PS. self.items is a list of words

Comment: `.pop(i)` is O(N), so it is O(N^2) overall. Generally, you just *make a new list filtering as you go*, which will be O(N), so `self.items = [i for i in self.items if i != item]` (or the equivalent for-loop would be just as good). Your approach *also* happens to incorrect, as it may skip items to remove (because you are mutating the list while iterating over it)

Comment: Be warry that except for being O(n^2) this code has other issues, such as changing the size of the list while iterating it

Comment: I don't understand how this code can work.`pop` takes an index, but you're giving it a list element.

Answer (score 2):

The `list.pop` method has an average and worst time complexity of *O(n)*, so compounded with the loop, it makes the code *O(n^2)* in time complexity.

And as @juanpa.arrivillaga has already pointed out in the comments, you can use a list comprehension instead to filter out items of a specific value in *O(n)* time complexity:

```
self.items = [i for i in self.items if i != item]
```

Comment: The worst case occurs if `item` occurs *n/2* times, say, and they all reside in the bottom half of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in self.items: # grows with the cardinal n of self.items
    if i == item:
        self.items.pop(i) # grows with the cardinal n of self.items
```

So you have a complexity of `O(n²)`.

The `list` method `remove(item)` in python though is of complexity `O(n)`, so you'd prefer use it.

```
self.items.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution has the time complexity of O(n^2).

For an O(n) solution you can just use for example an list comprehension to filter all the non wanted elements from the list:

```
self.items = [i for i in self.items if i != item]
```

Comment: Furthermore, this code actually works, because other codes change the size of the array while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd have to slightly adjust your code. The argument given to `pop()` is currently an item, where it should be an index (use `remove()` to remove the first occurrence of an item).

```
for i, item in enumerate(self.items):
        if item == target:
            self.items.pop(i)
```

The complexity depends on how often `item` matches the element in your list.

Using `n=len(items)` and `k` for the number of matches, the complexity is `O(n, k) = O(n) + k O(n)`. The first term comes from the fact that we iterate through the entire list, the second one corresponds to the individual `.pop(i)` operations.

The total complexity for `k=1` is thus simply `O(n)`, and could go up to `O(n*n)` for `k=n`.

Note that the complexity for `.pop(i)` is `O(n-i)`. Hence, popping the first and last element is `O(n)` and `O(1)`, respectively.

Lastly, I'd generally recommend not to add/remove items to an object that you're currently iterating over.